# White tab in bottom corner of Pygame window

Tags: python, pygame

Does anyone know why this white tab appears at the bottom of my Pygame window and if I can get rid of it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is to resize the window, so that you can go into (near) full screen if needbe. I don't get why you would want to get rid of it, because it is extremely useful for supporting many different resolutions.

Answer (score 1):

It's for resizing, and I don't think you can remove it without jumping through hoops .... And why would you want to? Remember, different people use different size monitors ... You want your game to be as dexterous as possible ...